# How to get the correct ListViewItem under the mouse cursor?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

The problem with the `ListView.GetItemAt` method is shown in the screenshot below.

## Designer code

```
this.listView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListView();
this.SuspendLayout();
// 
// listView1
// 
this.listView1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
this.listView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
this.listView1.Name = "listView1";
this.listView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(717, 511);
this.listView1.TabIndex = 0;
this.listView1.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
// 
// Form1
// 
this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(717, 511);
this.Controls.Add(this.listView1);
this.Name = "Form1";
this.Text = "Form1";
this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
this.ResumeLayout(false);
```

## Code-behind

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.OwnerDraw = true;
    listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;
    listView1.DrawItem += ListView1_DrawItem;
    listView1.MouseMove += ListView1_MouseMove;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add($"item {i}", 0);
    }
}

private void ListView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem item = listView1.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);

    if (LastHoveredItem != null)
    {
        ListViewItem item2 = LastHoveredItem;
        LastHoveredItem = null;
        listView1.Invalidate(item2.Bounds);
    }

    if (item != null)
    {
        LastHoveredItem = item;
        listView1.Invalidate(item.Bounds);
    }
    else
    {
        LastHoveredItem = null;
    }
}

private void ListView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (LastHoveredItem == e.Item)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Yellow, e.Item.Bounds);
    }
    else
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, e.Item.Bounds);
    }
}

internal ListViewItem LastHoveredItem = null;
```

## Screenshot

The rectangle under the mouse cursor should be yellow, but it is green like the others that are not hovered.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You don't need to find hot item in mouse move. In mouse move you just need to call `InValidate`

Comment: @RezaAghaei In the MouseMove handler I need to Invalidate only one or two items, not the entire ListView, so I think that finding the hot item in MouseMove is the best way.

Comment: You know your requirements, even if you want to find it in the mouse move, use the method overloads which is mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListView.GetItemAt` gets the item if the label or icon rectangle of the icon contains the point. It's not what you are looking for. You need to check the entire item.

You can use either of the following methods:

- [`ListView.GetItemRect(int, ItemBoundsPortion)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.getitemrect?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_ListView_GetItemRect_System_Int32_System_Windows_Forms_ItemBoundsPortion_)
- [`ListViewItem.GetBounds(ItemBoundsPortion)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.getbounds?view=netframework-4.7.2)

**Example - Detect hot item in DrawItem**

```
private void listView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    //...
    var p = listView1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
    if (e.Item.GetBounds(ItemBoundsPortion.Entire).Contains(p))
    {
        //e.Item is Hot
    }
    else
    {
        //e.Item is Normal
    }
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use the listView1.FocusedItem property

Answer (score 0):

Sharing an alternative solution that find the ListViewSubItem under the mouse cursor, credits to Fredrik Mörk (appsloveworld.com):

```
    private void listViewCreateEntity_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control == true && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
        {
            var mousePos = listViewCreateEntity.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
            ListViewItem lvItem = listViewCreateEntity.GetItemAt(mousePos.X, mousePos.Y);
            if (null != lvItem)
            {
                var lvSubItem = lvItem.GetSubItemAt(mousePos.X, mousePos.Y);
               Clipboard.SetText(lvSubItem.Text);
                Debug.WriteLine("Hit! Clipboard copy: " + lvSubItem.Text);
            }
        }
    }
```